# TimeLineMax() class doesn't resolve even with including the cdn links

Tags: javascript, gsap

I'm using PHPstorm and I've placed the CDN links right before closing my  tag :

```js
const timeLine = new TimeLineMax();
timeLine.from(

  ...

);
```

```html
HTML code ...

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.1.1/gsap.min.js" type="text/javascript" defer></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/latest/TimelineMax.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/main-2.js" type="text/javascript" defer></script>

</body>

</html>
```

also I'v downloaded the gsap libraries in PHPstorm :
[screenshot of my editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9pm63.png)

But still the PHPstorm doesn't resolve the TimeLineMax() class in my JS file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's **TimelineMax**, not TimeLineMax. Besides, if you're loading GSAP 3 (like you are) you could/should be using GSAP 3's new API format:

```
const timeLine = gsap.timeline();
timeLine.from(target, {
  duration: 1,
  ...
});
```

You also don't need to load the TimelineMax file, it's included in the GSAP core file that you included. What you're doing is mixing versions, which won't work.

Comment: Thank you very much!But now the IDE can't resolve the gsap in gsap.timeline();

Comment: If you are loading `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.1.1/gsap.min.js" type="text/javascript" defer></script>` like you say that you are, and no other versions of GSAP, it should not be having that error.

Comment: Yeah,I find out that my gsap syntax was incorrect and the external links was fine.  My new syntax is : const tl = gsap.timeline();
                               tl.from(...);

Comment: @PARSASEDIGH If this answer solved the issue that you asked about, you should click the check mark next to the answer. If it didn't and you solved it yourself, it would be good to post what you did to solve it as a new answer.